# Jenkins GIT include regions never builds for

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to build my job in Jenkins using include regions, but whenever this option is checked the poll result always say that no change was detected.

I have tried a number of different paths. And with/without force polling using workspace.
The result is that the polling never detects any changes, but as soon as I remove these options they build on the next poll.

The job repo is checked out using sparse checkout, but I also tried cloning the entire repo and got the same result.

The Git plugin version is 2.2.1, and Jenkins version is 1.562

the path I set is typically path/path/.*

Answer (score 1):

It normally only works with "force polling using workspace". It may still not work due to this [Jenkins GIT Plugin Bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20607).