# jenkins included regions not work even choose force polling using workspace

Tags: git

- git 1.5.4
- jenkins 1.563
- git plugin 2.2.1

my git project is like so:

```
testproject/code/b2b/admin/...
testproject/code/b2b/app/...
testproject/code/b2c/admin/...
testproject/code/b2c/app/...
```

in Additional Behaviours section, I add Force polling using workspace. and also add Polling ignores commits in certain paths.

in Included Regions,I wrote

```
code/b2b/admin/.*
code/b2c/admin/.*
```

In build trigger section,I wrote `* * * * *` in Poll SCM but, no matter where I changed the code in testproject, it doesn't trigger.

Answer (score 1):

That polling plugin does indeed [seem to be broken](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11749?focusedCommentId=161243&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-161243), but as a Jenkins 1.x workaround you can use a downstream job, that's kicked off with a conditional step, which leverages the `git whatchanged` command.

> `git whatchanged "${GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT}".."${GIT_COMMIT}" | grep '^:' | cut -f 2 | grep '^{path}/'`

Here's a more readily useful snippet leveraging the `whatchanged` from a bit of [Jenkins Job Builder](https://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/builders.html#builders.conditional-step) code.

```
builders:
    - conditional-step:
        on-evaluation-failure: dont-run
        condition-kind: or
        condition-operands:
            - condition-kind: shell
              condition-command: |
                if [[ -z "${{GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT}}" ]]; then
                 echo 'GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT was empty'
                elif [[ "${{GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT}}" != "${{GIT_COMMIT}}" ]]; then
                 git whatchanged "${{GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT}}".."${{GIT_COMMIT}}" | grep '^:' | cut -f 2 | grep '^{path}/'
                else
                 # This should have been selected earlier as the build-cause operand of the conditional step...
                 echo 'previous and current commits match, implying the job is kicked off manually'
                fi
        steps:
          - trigger-builds:
            - project: 'downstream job'
              condition: SUCCESS
              block: true
              predefined-parameters: |
                GITREF=${{GIT_COMMIT}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905891/jenkins-git-include-regions-never-builds-for)

If testproject/ is the root path of your git repository then your regex is correct. I think this is the problem: [Jenkins GIT Plugin Bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20607)